# Firefox не блюрит дальше 61px

Tags: css, firefox, filter, blur

Я хочу сделать на заднем плане заблюранные "фонари".
Блюр довольно большой: 150px, но в Хроме и Сафари все хорошо работает.

Вот так это выглядит в Хроме и Сафари.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот так это выглядит на фаерфокс, причем я выяснил, что эта картина не меняется после 61-62px.
Дальше блюр просто не идет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body::after,
body::before {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  width: 270px;
  height: 270px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  filter: blur(150px);  
}
body::after {
  top: 42.8%;
  right: 25%;
  background-color: #7000ff;
}
body::before {
  top: 27.5%;
  left: 23.9%;
  background-color: #cc00ff;
}
```

Comment: Есть упоминания что блюр ограничен сотней пикселов. Обойдите это сделав блюр в два раза меньше, а scale картинки в два раза больше. Разница не будет заметна.

Comment: а если просто картинку заблюрить как надо и поставить её на фон ? так 100% будет работать везде одинакого

Comment: Не понимаю, о чём вы? [У меня всё работает нормально](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8ot3.png). Вот [блюр 61px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFlGj.png) для примера.